# ENXIO (No such device or address) trying to open /sys/bus/usb/devices/xxx although the corresponding file exists

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, usb, libusb

I'm trying to understand why libusb returns no devices under `root` user.

Here is its debug output

```
$ LIBUSB_DEBUG=4 lsusb
[timestamp] [threadID] facility level [function call] <message>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ 0.000011] [00000131] libusb: debug [libusb_init] created default context
[ 0.000044] [00000131] libusb: debug [libusb_init] libusb v1.0.23.11397
[ 0.000075] [00000131] libusb: debug [find_usbfs_path] found usbfs at /dev/bus/usb
[ 0.000095] [00000131] libusb: debug [get_kernel_version] reported kernel version is 4.4.180+
[ 0.000103] [00000131] libusb: debug [op_init] bulk continuation flag supported
[ 0.000106] [00000131] libusb: debug [op_init] zero length packet flag supported
[ 0.000108] [00000131] libusb: debug [op_init] max iso packet length is (likely) 49152 bytes
[ 0.000119] [00000131] libusb: debug [op_init] sysfs can relate devices
[ 0.000125] [00000131] libusb: debug [op_init] sysfs has complete descriptors
[ 0.000445] [00000132] libusb: debug [linux_udev_event_thread_main] udev event thread entering.
[ 0.000692] [00000131] libusb: debug [usbi_add_pollfd] add fd 6 events 1
[ 0.000708] [00000131] libusb: debug [usbi_io_init] using timerfd for timeouts
[ 0.000712] [00000131] libusb: debug [usbi_add_pollfd] add fd 8 events 1
[ 0.000716] [00000131] libusb: debug [libusb_get_device_list]
[ 0.000728] [00000131] libusb: debug [libusb_exit]
[ 0.000732] [00000131] libusb: debug [libusb_exit] destroying default context
[ 0.000744] [00000131] libusb: debug [libusb_handle_events_timeout_completed] doing our own event handling
[ 0.000752] [00000131] libusb: debug [handle_events] poll fds modified, reallocating
[ 0.000762] [00000131] libusb: debug [handle_events] poll() 2 fds with timeout in 0ms
[ 0.000770] [00000131] libusb: debug [handle_events] poll() returned 0
[ 0.000776] [00000131] libusb: debug [usbi_remove_pollfd] remove fd 6
[ 0.000787] [00000131] libusb: debug [usbi_remove_pollfd] remove fd 8
[ 0.000807] [00000132] libusb: debug [linux_udev_event_thread_main] udev event thread exiting
```

so according to the output `libusb_get_device_list` returns no devices.
In case of running lsusb with strace there is the following output

```
$ strace lsusb
execve("/usr/bin/lsusb", ["lsusb"], 0x7fff7377e4c0 /* 8 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55cc65ffa000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffd652c1750) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6608, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 6608, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fabcc083000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=109440, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fabcc081000
mmap(NULL, 111728, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fabcc065000
mmap(0x7fabcc069000, 57344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7fabcc069000
mmap(0x7fabcc077000, 32768, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12000) = 0x7fabcc077000
mmap(0x7fabcc07f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7fabcc07f000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=178528, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 182536, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fabcc038000
mmap(0x7fabcc03d000, 114688, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7fabcc03d000
mmap(0x7fabcc059000, 40960, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x21000) = 0x7fabcc059000
mmap(0x7fabcc063000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2a000) = 0x7fabcc063000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360q\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029224, ...}) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
mmap(NULL, 2036952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fabcbe46000
mprotect(0x7fabcbe6b000, 1847296, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fabcbe6b000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7fabcbe6b000
mmap(0x7fabcbfe3000, 303104, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19d000) = 0x7fabcbfe3000
mmap(0x7fabcc02e000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7fabcc02e000
mmap(0x7fabcc034000, 13528, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fabcc034000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\201\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\345Ga\367\265T\320\374\301V)Yf]\223\337"..., 68, 824) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=157224, ...}) = 0
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\345Ga\367\265T\320\374\301V)Yf]\223\337"..., 68, 824) = 68
mmap(NULL, 140408, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fabcbe23000
mmap(0x7fabcbe2a000, 69632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x7fabcbe2a000
mmap(0x7fabcbe3b000, 20480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7fabcbe3b000
mmap(0x7fabcbe40000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x7fabcbe40000
mmap(0x7fabcbe42000, 13432, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fabcbe42000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fabcbe21000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fabcbe21c00) = 0
mprotect(0x7fabcc02e000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fabcbe40000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fabcc063000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fabcc07f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55cc65edc000, 32768, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fabcc0b2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fabcc083000, 6608)            = 0
set_tid_address(0x7fabcbe21ed0)         = 310
set_robust_list(0x7fabcbe21ee0, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7fabcbe2abf0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fabcbe383c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7fabcbe2ac90, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fabcbe383c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55cc65ffa000
brk(0x55cc6601b000)                     = 0x55cc6601b000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/systemd/hwdb/hwdb.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/udev/hwdb.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/systemd/hwdb/hwdb.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/systemd/hwdb/hwdb.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/udev/hwdb.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/bus/usb", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=100, ...}) = 0
getdents64(3, /* 5 entries */, 32768)   = 128
close(3)                                = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="5f2a189ab7a0", ...}) = 0
stat("/sys/bus/usb/devices", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
access("/run/udev/control", F_OK)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
name_to_handle_at(AT_FDCWD, "/dev", {handle_bytes=128 => 12, handle_type=1, f_handle=0xc6817a616876070000000000}, [107], 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/mountinfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "105 75 0:34 /@syno/@docker/btrfs"..., 1024) = 1024
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
read(3, "dockerd.service /sys/fs/cgroup/s"..., 1024) = 1024
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
read(3, "89ab7a061cc62b5d73b31dc6853fd876"..., 1024) = 1024
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
read(3, "cachedev_0 rw,ssd,synoacl,space_"..., 1024) = 762
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd652c1340)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT) = 3
getpid()                                = 310
gettid()                                = 310
futex(0x7fabcc0640d0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, {len=10, filter=0x7ffd652c0420}, 16) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PASSCRED, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=310, nl_groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
pipe2([4, 5], O_CLOEXEC)                = 0
fcntl(5, F_GETFL)                       = 0x1 (flags O_WRONLY)
fcntl(5, F_SETFL, O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fabcb620000
mprotect(0x7fabcb621000, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fabcbe1ffb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tid=[311], tls=0x7fabcbe20700, child_tidptr=0x7fabcbe209d0) = 311
access("/sys/subsystem", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getdents64(6, /* 23 entries */, 32768)  = 656
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/usb/devices/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 7
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getdents64(7, /* 10 entries */, 32768)  = 272
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 8
openat(8, "sys", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 9
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
openat(9, "bus", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 8
fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(9)                                = 0
openat(8, "usb", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 9
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
openat(9, "devices", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 8
fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(9)                                = 0
openat(8, "1-2", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
close(8)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 8
openat(8, "sys", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 9
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
openat(9, "bus", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 8
fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(9)                                = 0
openat(8, "usb", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 9
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
openat(9, "devices", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 8
fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(9)                                = 0
openat(8, "1-4", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
close(8)                                = 0
...
...                             
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 8
openat(8, "sys", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 9
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
openat(9, "bus", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 8
fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(9)                                = 0
openat(8, "usb", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 9
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
openat(9, "devices", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = 8
fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(9)                                = 0
openat(8, "2-0:1.0", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
close(8)                                = 0
getdents64(7, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(7)                                = 0
getdents64(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getdents64(6, /* 51 entries */, 32768)  = 1488
getdents64(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(6)                                = 0
pipe2([6, 7], O_CLOEXEC)                = 0
fcntl(7, F_GETFL)                       = 0x1 (flags O_WRONLY)
fcntl(7, F_SETFL, O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0
write(7, "\1", 1)                       = 1
timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TFD_CLOEXEC|TFD_NONBLOCK) = 8
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=128}, 0)        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
read(6, "\1", 1)                        = 1
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
write(7, "\1", 1)                       = 1
close(6)                                = 0
close(7)                                = 0
close(8)                                = 0
write(5, "\1", 1)                       = 1
close(3)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I've implemented a simple program that repeats the same steps as libusb accessing /sys/bus/usb/devices subfolder

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int fd1 = openat(AT_FDCWD, "/", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY);
    if (fd1 == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    int fd2 = openat(fd1, "sys", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH);
    if (fd2 == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    close(fd1);

    fd1 = openat(fd2, "bus", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH);
    if (fd2 == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    close(fd2);

    fd2 = openat(fd1, "usb", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH);
    if (fd2 == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    close(fd1);

    fd1 = openat(fd2, "devices", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH);
    if (fd1 == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    close(fd2);

    fd2 = openat(fd1, "1-0:1.0", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH);
    if (fd2 == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);

    return 0;
}
```

and got the same error as well

```
open: No such device or address
```

I'm wondering what is the issue, and why `ENXIO` error continuous to occur because directory /sys/bus/usb/devices/ exists and I have access to all its subdirectories without any issue

```
$ ls -la /sys/bus/usb/devices/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Oct 28 11:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 0 Oct 28 11:13 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 28 10:56 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 28 10:56 1-2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 28 10:56 1-2:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 28 10:56 1-4 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 28 10:56 1-4:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 28 10:56 2-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 28 10:56 usb1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 28 10:56 usb2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb2
```

Could you please help me to understand why `openat(fd1, "1-0:1.0", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_PATH)` returns `ENXIO` although there is the corresponding file on the file system?

#### UPDATE 1

`dmesg` contains the following entries regarding the usb devices

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i usb
[   42.100961] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[   42.105481] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[   42.111630] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[   42.117599] usbcore: registered new interface driver ethub
[   42.123749] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[   42.155551] xhci_hcd 0000:00:15.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[   42.374758] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   42.621484] xhci_hcd 0000:00:15.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[   42.629817] usb usb2: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[   42.639138] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   42.938150] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   43.203104] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   63.260796] systemd[1]: Starting unbind USB device...
[   63.763323] systemd[1]: Started unbind USB device.
[   63.998358] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   63.998458] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[   63.998570] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   64.001510] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[   64.015745] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[   64.221017] systemd[1]: Starting Mount usb fs...
[   65.577197] usblp 1-2:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 2 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x042A
[   65.577223] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[   65.596955] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   65.596955] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   84.945348] usbip_core: usbip_core_init:813: USB/IP Core v1.0.0
[   84.957176] usbip 1-2:1.1: Enter probe
[   84.957181] usbip 1-2:1.1: 1-2 is not in match_busid table... skip!
[   84.965112] usbip 1-2:1.2: Enter probe
[   84.965117] usbip 1-2:1.2: 1-2 is not in match_busid table... skip!
[   84.972180] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbip
[   84.978321] usbip_host: usbip_host_init:279: USB/IP Host Driver v1.0.0
[  237.972223] usblp0: removed
[  238.115012] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  239.261550] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  239.597445] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  244.311999] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  244.886834] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  245.650632] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 1213.931679] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[182534.523961] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[182534.666153] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[182534.673301] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[182537.901266] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[182538.043284] usb 1-2: device firmware changed
[182538.048167] usb usb1-port2: logical disconnect on port 2 [usb-storage]
[182538.055713] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[182538.189993] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[182538.342120] usblp 1-2:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 5 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x042A
[182538.353265] usbip 1-2:1.1: Enter probe
[182538.353268] usbip 1-2:1.1: 1-2 is not in match_busid table... skip!
[182538.360529] usbip 1-2:1.2: Enter probe
[182538.360532] usbip 1-2:1.2: 1-2 is not in match_busid table... skip!
...
...
[583693.667045] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[583693.810710] usblp 1-2:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 9 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x042A
[583704.858854] usblp0: removed
[583705.197953] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[583705.589845] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[598926.707359] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[610901.604714] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[610901.747026] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[610901.754121] scsi host15: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[610904.981754] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[610905.123180] usb 1-2: device firmware changed
[610905.128052] usb usb1-port2: logical disconnect on port 2 [usb-storage]
[610905.135510] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 10
[610905.266891] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[610905.411137] usblp 1-2:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 11 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x042A
[610905.422386] usbip 1-2:1.1: Enter probe
[610905.422389] usbip 1-2:1.1: 1-2 is not in match_busid table... skip!
[610905.429643] usbip 1-2:1.2: Enter probe
[610905.429645] usbip 1-2:1.2: 1-2 is not in match_busid table... skip!
[613048.235294] usblp0: removed
[613048.470217] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[613048.862147] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[613049.128104] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[613049.518043] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[779309.148447] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[874275.433426] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[874275.576203] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[874275.583297] scsi host16: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[874278.809962] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[874278.951980] usb 1-2: device firmware changed
[874278.956862] usb usb1-port2: logical disconnect on port 2 [usb-storage]
[874278.964511] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 12
[874279.093704] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[874279.239720] usblp 1-2:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 13 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x042A
[874279.250993] usbip 1-2:1.1: Enter probe
[874279.250996] usbip 1-2:1.1: 1-2 is not in match_busid table... skip!
[874279.258281] usbip 1-2:1.2: Enter probe
[874279.258283] usbip 1-2:1.2: 1-2 is not in match_busid table... skip!
```

#### UPDATE 2

`ls -la /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:15.0/usb1/1-2/` returns the following

```
$ sudo ls -la /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:15.0/usb1/1-2/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root     0 Nov  8 22:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root     0 Nov  8 22:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     0 Nov  8 22:31 1-2:1.0
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     0 Nov  8 22:31 1-2:1.1
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     0 Nov  8 22:31 1-2:1.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 authorized
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 avoid_reset_quirk
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 bcdDevice
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 bConfigurationValue
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 bDeviceClass
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 bDeviceProtocol
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 bDeviceSubClass
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 bmAttributes
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 bMaxPacketSize0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 bMaxPower
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 bNumConfigurations
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 bNumInterfaces
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 busnum
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 configuration
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 65553 Nov  8 22:31 descriptors
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 dev
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 devnum
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 devpath
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Nov  8 22:31 driver -> ../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/usb
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     0 Nov  8 22:31 ep_00
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 idProduct
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 idVendor
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 ltm_capable
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 manufacturer
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 maxchild
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Nov  8 22:31 port -> ../1-0:1.0/usb1-port2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     0 Nov  8 22:31 power
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 product
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 quirks
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 removable
--w------- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 remove
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 serial
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 speed
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Nov  8 22:31 subsystem -> ../../../../../bus/usb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 syno_quirks
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 syno_vbus_reset
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 uevent
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 urbnum
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov  8 22:31 version
```

Comment: The kernel driver can return any error code it deems fit. If the kernel driver failed to open some underlying hardware, these things usually complain to the console. Anything interesting appeared in `dmesg`?

Comment: Show `ls -la /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2`

Comment: @dratenik, I've updated the post to contain `dmesg` usb entries

Comment: @stark, I've updated the post to contain `ls -la /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2` output